# Regex to filter occurrences

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to get the odd occurrences of delimiters along with the associated content to another file, but its not happening with `awk -F \# !'(NF % 2)' < file`

Below are the sample input and output files where `#` is the delimiter,

Input:

```
#123456789uyrtghfdjuerstijhbvgd#ytio6745234890
fdjuerstijhbgftre#5555555555555555555555yyyyyy
#reyigdwwiuyt6678890#qeewteuiroprvvcsderjkkkkk
```

Desired output:

```
#123456789uyrtghfdjuerstijhbvgd#5555555555555555555555yyyyyy
#qeewteuiroprvvcsderjkkkkk
```

Comment: That *output* is your desired output?

Comment: yes, just updated it as desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="#"}
     !(NR % 2) {printf("%s%s",ORS,$0)}' file
```

Prints:

```
#123456789uyrtghfdjuerstijhbvgd#5555555555555555555555yyyyyy
#qeewteuiroprvvcsderjkkkkk
```

Suppose your file is this (with `^#^` as a three character delimiter):

```
$ cat file
^#^123456789uyrtghfdjuerstijhbvgd^#^ytio6745234890
fdjuerstijhbgftre^#^5555555555555555555555yyyyyy
^#^reyigdwwiuyt6678890^#^qeewteuiroprvvcsderjkkkkk
```

You can use `gawk` (not POSIX `awk`) to do:

```
gawk 'BEGIN{RS="\\^#\\^";ORS="^#^"}
      !(NR % 2) {printf("%s%s",ORS,$0)}' file
^#^123456789uyrtghfdjuerstijhbvgd^#^5555555555555555555555yyyyyy
^#^qeewteuiroprvvcsderjkkkkk
```

Since `gawk` is using a regex as the value of `RS` and `^` is a regex metacharacter, it needs to be escaped to be a fixed string.